# Trouble with pointers and pointers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some trouble understanding why a piece of code works. The following is a comparison function for stdlib's implementation of qsort:

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void * p2)
{
  char *v1, *v2;

  v1 = (char *) p1;
  v2 = (char *) p2;
  return strcmp(v1,v2);
}
```

Naturally, this only works for strings. My question is: why does the code below work?

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void * p2)
{
  char *v1, *v2;

  v1 = *(char **) p1;
  v2 = *(char **) p2;
  return strcmp(v1,v2);
}
```

It seems to me that in the second version, I'm forcefully casting what clearly is a `char*` to `char**`. The problem is that the variable will still contain an address to a `char` variable. When I apply `*`, it is my understanding that C will process this command by fetching the contents of  `p1`, and then reading 8 bytes (on my arch) following the address stored inside, so that it will ultimately get a value of type `char*`.
This should, in my opinion, lead to conjoining 8 characters into an invalid memory address.

Still, both functions work equally well. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The second version seems correct to me. Hard to tell how the first version works without seeing rest of your code.

Comment: how do you call the function? If you call the function like that `scmp("hello", "hello");` only the first version will work: http://ideone.com/P96Wmj

Comment: It may seem to work in some cases but it won't work for all cases. If for example p1 points to string "abcdefgh" and p2 to another string "abcdefgh". Now the strings are equal so they are both interpreted as the same address (let's call it p). Then strcmp will compare the string at p to the string at p, and since both parameters point to the same address, the contents is by definition the same.

Comment: @RSahu: can you explain why it seems correct?

Comment: Before asking "Why is X true?", you should first ask, "Is X true?"  In this case, the second code block does not actually work so the question "Why does it work?" is invalid.

Comment: Both functions are correct depending on what `p1` and `p2` are, but the second one is the one to use as a compare function in `qsort()` on an array of char* (string).

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to sort an array of `int`s using `qsort`.

```
int numbers[] = {10, 50, 35, 62, 22};
```

First, you create a function that can compare two `int`s.

```
int intCompare(void* p1, void* p2)
{
   int n1 = *(int*)p1;
   int n2 = *(int*)p2;
   return (n1 < n2);
}
```

Then, you can use:

```
qsort(numbers, 5, sizeof(int), intCompare);
```

When `numbers` is passed to `qsort`, it is decayed to a `int*` and passed as `void*`. When we need to extract the number from a `void*` in `intCompare`, we need to cast it to `int*` before we dereference the pointer and compare the values.

Taking the analogy to strings, let's say you want to sort:

```
char* strings[] = { "abc", "xyz", "def" };
```

The call to `qsort` will be:

```
qsort(strings, 3, sizeof(char*), scmp);
```

When `strings` is passed to `qsort`, it is decayed to a `char**` and passed as `void*`. The underlying types of the pointers being passed to to `scmp` by `qsort` will be of type `char**`, not `char*`. Hence, it is correct to use:

```
int scmp(const void *p1, const void * p2)
{
  char *v1, *v2;

  v1 = *(char **) p1;
  v2 = *(char **) p2;
  return strcmp(v1,v2);
}
```

The first version works due to lucky coincidence in some cases. Here's an example program that shows couple of cases where it does not work while the second version should always work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// First version of scmp
int scmp1(const void *p1, const void * p2)
{
  char *v1, *v2;

  v1 = (char *) p1;
  v2 = (char *) p2;
  return strcmp(v1,v2);
}

// Second version of scmp
int scmp2(const void *p1, const void * p2)
{
  char *v1, *v2;

  v1 = *(char **) p1;
  v2 = *(char **) p2;
  return strcmp(v1,v2);
}

void test1()
{
   char* strings[] = { "abc", "xyz", "def" };
   qsort(strings,  3, sizeof(char*), scmp1);
   for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

void test2()
{
   char* strings[] = { "abc", "xyz", "def" };
   qsort(strings,  3, sizeof(char*), scmp2);
   for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

void test3()
{
   char** strings = malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
   strings[0] = "abc";
   strings[1] = "xyz";
   strings[2] = "def";

   qsort(strings,  3, sizeof(char*), scmp1);
   for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
   }

   free(strings);
   printf("\n");
}

void test4()
{
   char** strings = malloc(3*sizeof(char*));
   strings[0] = "abc";
   strings[1] = "xyz";
   strings[2] = "def";

   qsort(strings,  3, sizeof(char*), scmp2);

   for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
   }

   free(strings);
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   // Does not work.
   test1();

   // Should work always.
   test2();

   // Does not work.
   test3();

   // Should work always.
   test4();
}
```

Output (using gcc 4.8.4):

```
abc
xyz
def

abc
def
xyz

abc
xyz
def

abc
def
xyz
```

Comment: Good to see some very detailed answers. +1